# Import VBA code from a excel spreadsheet into a access form behind a button

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have an excel spreadsheet, and into that spreadsheet is a VBA script written by myself.

Frequently I have to make some changes to the code and copy (ctrl-C) this code in a form behind a button (by a on-click event), using (ctrl-V)

Is it possible to do this automatically in an Access procedure when I make changes in the spreadsheet (VBA-code), so that I can import this VBA code in Access 2007?

Answer (score 0):

Metaprogramming in VBA can be an interesting topic. You'd want to look up the VBIDE library. I'd probably start with the [CodeModule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa443970(v=vs.60).aspx) object and [Chip Pearson's "Programming The VBA Editor"](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx).

The example below inserts a module scoped private constant containing the module's name into the active code pane.

```
Private Sub insertModuleName()
' inserts a module name constant into every module in active project

    Dim oPrj As VBProject
    Set oPrj = VBE.ActiveVBProject
    Dim oMod As CodeModule
    Dim oCom As VBComponent

    Dim str As String
    str = "Private Const MODULE_NAME As String = "

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To oPrj.VBComponents.count
       oPrj.VBComponents.Item(i).CodeModule.InsertLines 3, str & Chr(34) & oPrj.VBComponents.Item(i).NAME & Chr(34)
    Next i
End Sub
```